# CSS overflow with floated DIV

Tags: html, css

My desire is when the screen size is reduced, an overflow scrollbar appears on `#content`.

It does so with Firefox, however, the background does not cover the content to the right of the scrollbar.

Furthermore, IE and Chrome both push `#content` down, and don't even show a scrollbar.

EDIT.  Below is an image showing my desired appearance.  Note that `#content` has a scroll bar.

[image]
How is this accomplished?

https://output.jsbin.com/huwagajome

```css
                body,div {margin:0;padding:0;}
    
                #header { height:60px; background:url(http://s1.postimg.org/e250ntgmz/header.png) repeat-x #e2e2e2;}
                #footer { height:60px; background:url(http://s8.postimg.org/3td1ckaph/footer.png) repeat-x #e2e2e2;}
    
                #wrapper {
                    background-image:url(http://s24.postimg.org/781yqtfdh/background2.jpg);
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    background-size: cover;
                    background-position: center;
                    height:840px;
                }
                #sidebar {
                    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
                    border-right: 4px solid #f15a29;
                    height:100%;
                    width:50px;
                    float:left;
                }
                #sidebar p {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
                    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
                    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
                    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
                    transform: rotate(-90deg);
                    position: relative;
                    top: 50%;
                    font-size:30px;
                    white-space: nowrap;
                }
    
                #content {
                    margin:0 auto;
                    padding-top:45px;
                    width: 960px;
                    height:100%;
                    /*overflow-x:auto;*/
                    overflow:auto;
                    /* position:relative; */
                    /* clear:both; */
                }
```

```html
            <div id="header"></div>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="sidebar"><p>Sidebar</p></div>
                <div id="content">
                    Ius ne quod posidonium, agam apeirian gubergren id eos, dolores percipit vis ex. Ex discere liberavisse his, sonet nominati conclusionemque et vis. Et admodum oporteat sit, eam facer affert mediocritatem ad, mea id omnium instructior. Pri ex natum option incorrupte, sit unum pertinax theophrastus ut.
    
                    Nam an saperet delectus tractatos. Ad option persecuti appellantur usu. Dicta habemus fuisset per ea, ius adhuc iracundia ei. Te timeam integre pro, ex dolore possim audiam vis.
    
                    Nam te tamquam omittam, eu diceret complectitur ius, quem omnesque sensibus in vel. Has eirmod accumsan atomorum ut, vel ei quod omittantur, expetendis neglegentur eu vim. Ad audiam fuisset cum. Quis mutat fabellas te nam, usu ut sumo suscipiantur, eos at lorem aeque graeci. In paulo disputationi ius, vide dissentias sadipscing eos cu.
    
                    Usu te graece vivendo, ludus latine nonumes te has. Pri id quando tantas offendit, nam ea viderer dissentiet. Facilis consequat concludaturque sea ut, an mel persius evertitur eloquentiam. Facilisis repudiare conceptam sit an.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: use `overflow-x:auto` for horizontal overflow. Also to trigger it when its a small screen size only you can use media queries.

Comment: @PetrosKyriakou `overflow-x:auto` has no other effect.  I originally thought it would be appropriate, but don't know anymore.  Never heard of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries before, and will investigate.  Still, nothing works with IE and Chrome.

Comment: Kind of hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to have a horizontal scroll or a veritcal one? `#content` has a fixed width causing it break when you have a smaller screen size. Give it a max-width and get rid of the float to get rid of the collapsing behavior, but not sure if that is what you're looking for.

Comment: @RooWM  I added an image to the original post.  Don't want `max-width`, but instead wish `#content` to keep its width and use a scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `min-width` to `#wrapper`.  Not only will it work with IE and Chrome, FF will cover all content.

```
#wrapper{min-width:  1015px;/*960px(content)+50px(sidebar)+ a little extra for good measures*/}
```

https://output.jsbin.com/nuholiguso